# Open different activities based on Spinner Selection - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, spinner

I am new to Kotlin and Android Studio and I am attempting to do something that I think should be fairly easy but I can't seem to get it.

I have a spinner populated with countries.  For each selection, I would like to open the corresponding activity.  I tried an If statement but I can only pass a string it seems:

button.setOnClickListener {

```
        if (country == "France") {
            val intent = Intent(this, FranceSelect::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        } else if (country == "Spain") {
            val intent = Intent(this, SpainSelect::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        val intent = Intent(this, CountrySelect::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

etc.

I would appreciate any help I can get with this.

Thank you.

Comment: please post your code

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I was missing parens around my string.

I now have it as

```
button.setOnClickListener { 
if (country == ("France")) 
{ val intent = Intent(this, FranceSelect::class.java) 
startActivity(intent) } 
else if (country == ("Spain")) 
{ val intent = Intent(this, SpainSelect::class.java)
 startActivity(intent) } 
}
```

Seem`enter code here`s to have solved the issue.

Thank you